# How to start many node scripts at once, or connect each with main to start together

Tags: mysql, node.js

Maybe my question is not good but It is my first time using node.js
I have `index.js` the main script that is the socket server. And I have another script for pull data from database.
I starting main `index.js` with npm start on port 3000, and if I want to use the other script I need to start that script `users_contacts.js` on port 3001 or something else other than 3000. Is it another way to start and using both of the scripts.

**users_contacts.js**

```
var express   =    require("express");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app       =    express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "192.168.0.0",
    port: "33991",
    user: "root",
    password: "******",
    database: "app_test"
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});

function handle_database(req,res) {
    // connection will be acquired automatically
    connection.query("select * from users",function(err,rows){
        if(err) {
            return res.json({'error': true, 'message': 'Error occurred'+err});
        }
        //connection will be released as well.
        res.json(rows);
    });
}

app.get("/",function(req,res){-
    handle_database(req,res);
});

app.listen(3002);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant run two processes in the same port, but you can concatenate your scripts this way:

```
script1 && script2 && script3...
```

Comment: node index.js && users_contacts.js you mean like this? in package.json

Comment: You can use "start" : "node index.js && node users_contact.js"

Comment: Then you can use concurrently -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently, use it as "start" : "concurrently command1 command2"